# Saving an html file from an excel cell

Tags: html, excel, saving-data

I'm using excel and I've got 400 rows in which I have my desired file name in one column and the desired html code for that file in another.

I was wondering if it's possible (en masse) to save the contents of the html code, using the associated file name so that each one is its own file?

```
HTMLtitle,HTMLcode
example1.html,"<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>example 1</html>"
example2.html,"<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>example 2</html>"
example3.html,"<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>example 3</html>"
example4.html,"<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>example 4</html>"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly copy the following code into a general module and run the procedure CreateBulkHTMLfilesFromExcelRanges and let me know.

This method is first creating a temporary file into a temporary folder and then it read texts from it and replaces the quotation mark using replace function.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As LongPtr, ByVal lpbuffer As String) As Long

Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260

Sub CreateBulkHTMLfilesFromExcelRanges()

    Dim myFile As String, i As Integer
    Dim iFile As Integer: iFile = VBA.FreeFile
    Dim OutputFolder As String
    Dim tmpFile As String
    Dim MyData As String, strData As String
    Dim entireline As String

    'We will create a Output Folder Dynamically in the Desktop
    OutputFolder = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\Output"

    'Check if the output folder exists or not. if it doesn't then it will create one.
    If VBA.Len(VBA.Dir(OutputFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        VBA.MkDir OutputFolder
    End If

    'Creating Files one by one
    For i = 2 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 1
        '~~> Create a Temp File
        tmpFile = TempPath & Format(Now, "ddmmyyyyhhmmss") & ".txt"
        Open tmpFile For Output As #iFile
        Write #iFile, Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Close #iFile

        '~~> Read the entire file in 1 Go!
        Open tmpFile For Binary As #1
        MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
        Get #1, , MyData
        Close #1
        strData = MyData

        '~~> Rewrite file
        myFile = OutputFolder & Application.PathSeparator & Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Open myFile For Output As #iFile
        entireline = Replace(strData, """", "")
        Print #iFile, entireline
        Close #iFile
    Next i

End Sub

'Following is the Function to get the temporary folder

Function TempPath() As String
    TempPath = String$(MAX_PATH, Chr$(0))
    GetTempPath MAX_PATH, TempPath
    TempPath = Replace(TempPath, Chr$(0), "")
End Function
```

Comment: @TommyE: Please upvote my answer if it really helped you. and also suggesting you select answers as useful. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing I have now realised. It seems to add double quotes to any html existing double quotes when you save it as an html file. Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: @TommyE: Kindly see the code now. It is updated and the issue was resolved. If it is okay now then please accept my answer and ticked as the useful. Thank you.

Comment: @TommyE: Did you checked the updated answer? Please check.

Comment: Hi Kamal, I ran into an error which said: "The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statement and hen mark them with the PtrSafe attribut" - any idea how I fix that?

Comment: @TommyE: I have updated the code again. Please check again and let me know if you find any more trouble. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Kamal, it seems to have replaced all " entirely (there are no longer any in the html code at all) so doesn't quite solve the problem.

Comment: @TommyE can u please write here how it should look like? and probably why you want " (quotes) with HTML code? because it is the same element that shows quotes on the result. kindly see your second comment. or let me know where I'm mistaking~!  I really want this to work for you. waiting for your reply.